# Query for preferred phone number types

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a query that would result in one row per record based on the value in one of the columns, in this case it's a phone number type. Certain types are more useful to me than others so I've been trying to select the order they are chosen. For example: if there is a "home" number I want that row first (because ne person can have multiple rows if they have multiple phone numbers), if there isn't a home number then give me a cell phone number, if there isn't a home or cell phone give me a work number...

I thought an IF/THEN/ELSE might be a good fit but it's just different enough from a simple formula in Excel that I'm just not writing it the right way. Or, it's very possible there's an even better way? I had something like this at my previous workplace (well before I was dabbling in sql) and they said it worked like a "waterfall", and I remember thinking it looked very basic and short but it's just not coming to me.

I'd love a nudge in the right direction.

Update:
Here is an greatly reduced version of the table (with nonsense randomized phone numbers), working in SQL Server

| ID_no | type | phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 408419 | 1 | 4401600 |
| 408419 | 13 | 4867631 |
| 406767 | 1 | 9183808 |
| 406767 | 13 | 6355198 |
| 410501 | 13 | 4336010 |
| 405193 | 8 | 2070904 |
| 405193 | 3 | 1512081 |
| 410501 | 8 | 8148225 |
| 407309 | 8 | 5195868 |
| 409858 | 8 | 3345459 |
| 408266 | 1 | 1054263 |

I want only one row per ID_no, and I would like to select which row based on the Type, and I would define an order of "importance" for those types. If I defined my order as Type 1,5,8,13,3 my results for the above would look like this:

| ID_no | type | phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 408419 | 1 | 4401600 |
| 406767 | 1 | 9183808 |
| 410501 | 13 | 4336010 |
| 405193 | 8 | 2070904 |
| 410501 | 8 | 8148225 |
| 407309 | 8 | 5195868 |
| 409858 | 8 | 3345459 |
| 408266 | 1 | 1054263 |

only one row per ID_no left

Comment: Please provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result. If you are looking for a single person, then you can rank the phones, then use an `ORDER BY` clause by the rank, and finally limit the result to 1.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Need to see what your table and data looks like.

Comment: tag with database, show all table DDL, sample data, and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```
with data as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (
            partition by ID_no
            order by case type
                when  1 then 1 when 5 then 2 when 8 then 3
                when 13 then 4 when 3 then 5 else 6 end
        ) as rn
    from T
)
select ID_no, type, phone from data where rn = 1;
```